# My Domain: Why prevent login from login.salesforce.com?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, federated-authentication, mydomain

I'm setting up My Domain with OKTA and was curious about the option to prevent login from login.salesforce.com.  The documentation doesn't have much on this option and couldn't figure out why I'd want to do (or not do) it.  Why would one want to enable this feature?

Answer (score 2):

This option is useful for organizations who want to apply strict domain policies. Moreover we have seen organizations going for Single-sign on policies going for this.

Comment: Nice. Additionally, it's not possible to log into orgs other than your own, from the My Domain hostname.

Comment: Idea being that they could whitelist mydomain.my.salesforce.com, and prevent access to other salesforce.com URLs?